# While carrying out data normalisation should I apply different techniques on different features

Tags: dataset, normalization, data-mining

I have been trying to normalize my data set which contains a number of features with different distributions, normalized, positively skewed and negatively skewed.
While carrying out data normalization as a preliminary step to building up a classification model, should I apply the same normalization technique to all features within the data set or should I apply different normalization techniques for different features within the data set?

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe**.

There is no one-size-fits-all rule.

If you e.g. have x,y coordinates on a small scale, yes then using the same normalization is probably more appropriate. Same as in "same scale", not just "same method". If you have latitude and longitude, do not do *any* normalization, unless you have reasons to assume earth was distorted.
And if you have completely different scales, say attribute A is "shoe-size", and attribute B is "pi / shoe-size", then YES, you will need different normalization for these two attributes.

Usually, when this question arises, you have not yet understood your data.